# VDF / RSA groups

Tags: rsa, group-theory

I believe I am overthinking it; however, I need to clear out my doubts.

What is exactly RSA groups and how their order is unknown? I know in RSA N  is computed by multiplying two prime numbers (p and q) and it is hard to find p and q given N. Is N what is called RSA group?

In VDF they use unknown order of RSA group; however, N is public.

Answer (score 7):

The RSA group for modulus $N$ of secret factorization simply is the [multiplicative group of integers modulo $N$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_N), often noted $\mathbb Z_N^*$. That can be viewed or defined as the subset of integers $m$ in the interval $[0,N)$ with $\gcd(N,m)=1$. The group law is multiplication modulo $N$, that is $a*b$ is the remainder of the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) of $a\times b$, where $\times$ is integer multiplication.

That group has order¹ the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(N)$. That quantity is unknown, since the factorization of $N$ is. We can easily compute $\varphi(N)$ if we know the factorization of $N$, and it turns out we can factor $N$ if we know $N$ and $\varphi(N)$.

Note: RSA encryption/decryption is often operating on the full [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) $[0,N)$ under multiplication modulo $N$, rather than it's group subset $\mathbb Z_N^*$. This requires that $N$ is [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) for decryption to work reliably.

---

In Benjamin Wesolowski's [*Efficient Verifiable Delay Functions*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623.pdf) (in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 2019](https://doi.org//10.1007/978-3-030-17659-4_13)), $(\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z)^×$ is $\mathbb Z_N^*$. Their notation reflects a construction of this group as the restriction to invertible elements of the quotient set of [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) in integers (that they note $\mathbf Z$ rather than $\mathbb Z$ above), for the equivalence relation *congruent² modulo $N$*, under the law $×$ which is compatible with this equivalence relation. I get this is how real math guys do it; I'm not really one.

See [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/201091) for more references on VDFs.

---

¹ that is, since it's a finite set, it's number of elements.

² by definition, $a\equiv b\pmod N\iff\exists q,\,a=b+q\times N$, with all quantities in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: VDFs were defined [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/601), to be precise. ([This](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/712) is a good survey.)

Answer (score 0):

> how their order is unknown?

The RSA public key may be generated using multiparty computation (MPC) (or, less nicely, by a third trusted party). Then, N is indeed public, but p and q are not, and so the group order is unknown.