# Can we instantiate VRF without using pairing?

Tags: pairings, verifiable-random-function

As my survey, most of(I am not sure if it is "all") the constructions of VRF are instantiated with the use of pairing. Can we construct a VRF without using pairing?

Comment: [This survey](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/VDFsurvey.html) mentions two schemes where I see no pairing, including Wesolowski's [_Efficient Verifiable Delay Functions_](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623.pdf), (in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 2019](https://doi.org//10.1007/978-3-030-17659-4_13)). Both are in comment or answer to a [related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/91461/555).

Comment: Additionally, we can mention VRFs based on the DDH assumption (https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/099), lattices (https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1222.pdf) or sequential evaluations of Legendre symbols (https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/182.pdf).

Comment: @IstvánAndrásSeres Thanks! That's what I want.